# src of Hello World is empty

Tags: android, adt

I just started Android programing. I had tried the Hello World tutorial, but every time src folder is empty. `MainActivity.java` file isn't generated. I use the latest ADT Bundle for Windows 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that came up recently.

To fix it, you'll either will have to wait for a patched ADT version, or roll back to an older version, like [22.3.0](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip)